# need way for haproxy to select backend node based on request header

Tags: haproxy

Is there a way to by pass the round robin server selection in the backend based on a request header?

The problem being if i always dedication PUT requests in an rest api, and in the application need to turn around and make a GET request on that api, but the original put request didnt replicate to the 2nd server, then the subsequent GET will fail.

Thought being if on the initial PUT, specified the server that took the request I could tell that to the application and when it immediately tried to lookup that new resource, i could say direct my guest GET to that server.

What i had in mind is somewhat like the directions for persistent connections outlined here:

http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/03/29/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/

```
     backend bk_web
       balance roundrobin
       cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache
       server s1 192.168.10.11:80 check cookie s1
       server s2 192.168.10.21:80 check cookie s2
```

But instead of queing this off on a cookie, one that will be set through lifetime of the session. This would, on a given request, beable to check header and redirect accordingly

Comment: Have you tried making the session sticky in haproxy?  That's usually the simple way to solve these issues.

Comment: I thought that, but a couple issues with that 1) i wouldnt want that to persist but just to initiate on command and 2) this is an application communicating to an api, not a user requesting the application. ie the documentation i read on persistent sessions, wouldnt work, as its based on a cookie.

Comment: As long as you are using a "real client" for the PUT, then a cookie will work.  Even cURL supports cookies.  Of course the real question is why do you need them to go to the same server in the first place, defeating the purpose of load balanced servers.  Your PUT should do what it needs to do in such a way that GET will work no matter what server it goes to.

Comment: Agreeing with @user3137702 the fact that this is an issue seems to highlight a weakness in the underlying design... but what about using `balance uri`?  It's not as "fair" as roundrobin but it's going to be reasonably close in most cases.